# Mysql update statement execution

Tags: mysql

I have a query as follows:

```
update `$inventory` as a                                                                                   
    join `$invoiceItems` as b on                                                                                     
        a.`$invoiceRef` = b.`$invoiceRef` and a.`drug-id` = b.`drug-id` and a.`batch-number` = b.`batch-number`  
    join `$invoices` as c on a.`$invoiceRef` = c.id                                                                  
    set a.`quantity` = a.`locked-quantity`, `locked-quantity` = 0                                                                                            
    where a.`$invoiceRef` = :invoice_id and c.`dispatch-status` = '$dispatched'
```

I am trying to copy value from `locked-quantity` into quantity and set `locked-quantity` = 0 in the same statement.

This works correctly MOST of the time. But once in a while I find that quantity gets 0 value. As if the second part of the set statement got evaluated first.

As per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html:

```
Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to right
```

The "generally" part has got me worried. Does it mean sometime it may not be evaluated left to right ?

It is possible the quantity gets 0 value due to some other bug, but to start with I want to make sure that this query is not the culprit. Has anyone experienced a similar problem ?

Comment: The code seems to run without error (though is not optimal), so at this point you might want to add some sample data which makes your question reproducible.  Otherwise, all most readers can do is to guess.

Comment: Is this really a single-table UPDATE statement? 'For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order.'

Comment: @user207421 Multiple table update statement has a different syntax. This is certainly a single table statement.

Comment: As an aside, allowing '-' within a table/column identifier is a bad idea.

Comment: @Strawberry Would like to know why..

Comment: It has a different syntax that appears to include any JOIN statement, which makes this a multiple table update. In any case you certainly should not be relying on 'generally'.

Comment: Because one day, you're going to have a column name locked and a column named quantity, and you're not going to know why you're query returns the wrong result. Or, worse, you're not even going to know that the result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

if its working fine have a small suggestion use `a.locked-quantity = 0`   not `locked-quantity`=0

```
update `$inventory` as a                                                                                   
    join `$invoiceItems` as b on                                                                                     
        a.`$invoiceRef` = b.`$invoiceRef` and a.`drug-id` = b.`drug-id` and a.`batch-number` = b.`batch-number`  
    join `$invoices` as c on a.`$invoiceRef` = c.id                                                                  
    set a.`quantity` = a.`locked-quantity`,a.`locked-quantity` = 0                                                                                           
    where a.`$invoiceRef` = :invoice_id and c.`dispatch-status` = '$dispatched' and a.`locked-quantity`!=0
```